# Get row with a symbol after a particular index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df:

```
Index col1
1     Abc
2     xyz
3     $123
4     wer
5     exr
6     ert
7     $546
8     $456
```

**Problem Statement**:

**Now I want to find the index of the row containing the dollar sign after the keyword** `wer`.

My Code:

```
idx = df.col1.str.contains('\$').idxmax() ## this gives me index 3 but what i want is index 7
```

Help need to modify my code to get the desired output

Comment: What value do you want if the condition is never met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mask the `wer` as well

```
s = (df['col1'].str.contains('\$')           # rows containing $
     & df['col1'].eq('wer').cumsum().gt(0)   # rows after the first 'wer'
    ).idxmax()
# s == 7
```

Comment: Thanks the solution worked well and also upvoted it, small query instead of using the "wer" in the same code how can I use the index of "wer" .. 4 in this case!!

Comment: if you already have `idx = 4`: `df.loc[idx:,'col1'].str.contains('\$').idxmax()` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#df=df.set_index('Index') #if 'index' is a column
df2=df[df['col1'].eq('wer').cumsum()>0]
df2['col1'].str.contains('\$').idxmax()
```

or:

```
df[(df['col1'].eq('wer').cumsum()>0) & df['col1'].str.contains('\$')].index[0]
```

Output:

```
7
```

**Details:**

```
df['col1'].eq('wer').cumsum().eq(1)
Index
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(df2)
       col1
Index      
4       wer
5       exr
6       ert
7      $546
8      $456
```

Comment: Similar to my approach, but you need to change `eq(1)` to `ge(1)` in case there are two `wer` before the next `$`

Comment: well seen. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks upvoted the answer...Small query instead of using the "wer" in the same code how can I use the index of "wer" .. 4 in this case!!